How common is voluntary (unauthorised) overtime during public holidays in the IT sector of Germany?
This is not a legal question. I am aware of the legislation regarding overtime in Germany; and there are plenty of posts here (e.g. WorkplaceSE/46653, WorkplaceSE/45108, etc.) that discuss the legal implications.
Since I do not have direct access to the German labour market nor have I found "real world" statistics of activities that may not fully align with the legal framework, I come here seeking insight into the German work culture from your anecdotal answers.
Kindly enlighten us as to how much reality conforms with what-should-be-ideally and what perhaps falls in the legally grey area but is still pretty prevalent. Thank you.

Just ask companies that employ IT staff for copies of the employment contracts. Untll you have that, this is an opinion based question.

Yes, people often work long hours at startups.  Maybe accept that your friend’s priorities differ from yours.

How common is it... well, it depends.
If you are self-employed (or owner of a company) you can pretty much do whatever you want and many who are directly invested in the success of a company go to great length for it. There are very little laws that tell owners how or what to do with their own time.
For independent contractors it is very common to work through public holidays that fall on a weekday. Because while they have the right to take that day off, it means they do not get paid for any work. So for contractors, that basically is an unpaid day off. Especially if the contractor lives in a different city and drives home for the weekend, they would rather work and make money, than sit in their hotel room unpaid on a weekday. Public holidays on a single weekday are mostly of smaller significance (unlike Christmas or Easter) and are rarely celebrated with anything special, so it's not like they "miss Christmas with the kids". For the kids it's just a lucky break from school they use for playing computer games or meeting with friends.
For regular employees it is super uncommon. Why would they. It is a paid day off. In some more regulated, unionized industries (certainly not tech startups) overtime pay on sundays and public holidays is significantly more, so employers would not want that, unless it is crucial to the business. If the work could be done the next business day or the day before, even with overtime, that would be cheaper and therefor preferable.
Sometimes, people in tech do work that is best done when all other employees are not working. Maintenance, deployment of new software, exchanging server hardare etc. For those, weekends or public holidays are nice. I have worked through Easter and Christmas at times. But it was voluntarily. I offered it. My boss would never have asked for it. He would even decline to ask for more volunteers to not be seen as coercing. I had to bring him 3 of my peers who all volunteered. So yes, it is possible, but it is voluntary and nobody thinks any less of those who don't volunteer. Especially those who do, who are mostly young singles, are perfectly fine with the family people skipping on this. One day, they will be the "family people" and they will not come forward and they expect that to be fine, too.
Now, I cannot speak to the company culture of startups hiring people very much dependent on them for their residence allowance. That seems like the obvious candidate for bad practices, cut corners, labor law violations and all kinds of shitty behavior. I'm not saying it has to happen, but that is certainly the point where it would be easiest and therefor most likely (no oversight, no structures of compliance or HR, no unions, parts of labor law only apply for companies over a certain size, the fear of having to leave the country always over peoples heads).
Overtime is nothing you can just "do". First off, your employer has to agree. They signed a contract to pay X for Y amount of time, you cannot just one-sidedly decide that this doesn't work for you and you want X+? for Y+?. That can only be done by both sides agreeing. Normally, overtime is simply taken as time off at the next opportune moment. In other words if I do 3 hours of overtime on Tuesday, because this production bug has to be fixed as soon as possible, I could come in 3 hours later on Wednesday. Or like most people do it, they collect the overtime over the course of the week and leave early on Friday. For most people, that is not overtime, that is just flexible working hours. We would consider it overtime, when you work more than your contractual hours per week.
However, Germany has laws about this. You are not allowed to work more than 10 hours a day, and not allowed to work more than 8 hours a day, unless you can compensate it with time off in a period of 24 weeks so that your average per working day over that period is 8 hours per working day again.
So you cannot really do overtime in Germany if you mean just constantly working longer for money. Not in the amount your friend is probably doing. It is not legal. It would be the employers obligation to tell your friend to stop that. Obviously the employer cannot tell your friend what they should do on their day off, so if they sit on their own computer and study something useful for work on their own... I guess that is well within their rights.
One other aspect that is a bit touchy... other cultures obviously have different cultural norms what is acceptable to put on your CV. Germans are very factual and understated. Other cultures, especially the Inidan subcontinent, is more... creative. If I read an Indian CV, I know that I basically need to decrease all levels by 2 to reach a German CV. Whether that is because people are just more polite to the point of lying, if they feel they need to embellish their resume, maybe their education system failed them and even though they went to university, they came out with way less relevant knowledge than German students of the same topic... I feel like it might be unfair to say they lie, but lets put it this way... if a German gave me the same CV, I would say they are a blatant liar and would never look at their applications again. So if your friend is from such a country and for whatever reason has interviewed with a CV that said a lot of things they cannot live up to in reality, then they might feel the (real) need to put in a lot more time than others, just to catch up to their own CV. I have seen this happen. It's not pretty, but I don't know how to help. If people claim to be an expert in X, and when they get a task to do X need to study all weekend to get a grasp of the basics for monday at work, that is kinda self-inflicted. It's also not overtime in the classical sense. The company neither knows nor pays for it.
Okay, that was a lot of text to say "it depends". Overtime like this is not normal for employees. Small startups are prone to do "not normal" things. Especially if the employees compare themselves to the founders, who are owners and therefor in a completely different position concerning overtime than their employees.
What does that mean for your friend? Well, if they break laws, that is a good indication that this is not how we do things here. They should at least keep that as a guideline. If the company is asking employees to break laws, that is a clear sign that they need to switch companies.
On the other hand, I cannot decide for your friend. If they prioritize their residence permit over everything else, "keep going, do everything they want without complaining until the two years are up" might be their preferred way of action. I have seen people do worse for less. It is their life and their priorities. Just because it's not normal, doesn't mean it isn't the best decision for them in their specific situation.

I have a friend that also earns quite little compared to his skill and experience and he still works a lot of overtime (most of it probably unpaid).
BUT he loves what he does, his company has an open source product where he also dedicates a lot of his (work) time.
As I see it, as long as you are not pressured (directly or indirectly) and do it voluntatrily, I see no issue with this from an ethical standpoint.
Me and my friend live in Austria, so very similar laws and work culture as Germany.

Take a person working 40 hours a week and a person working 60 hours a week. It has been demonstrated by studies that for about six weeks, both have the same productivity. Unfortunately not the same productivity per hour, but per day. Which means the person working 20 hours more has zero benefit from it, nor has their company.
However, after six weeks you have one worker who is fresh and can go on for months and months. The other one is exhausted. So six weeks is about the point where your productivity actually drops.
Now what might stop him is that he can get into serious trouble with his company. The company has to pay for overtime. Statute of limitations is probably six years, meaning a rogue employee can ask for extra money for six years. Tell his manager. His manager will not be happy. Not at all. It will probably come as a big shock to your colleague, but doing overtime without asking will not count in his favour.
In addition, nobody thinks any better of you for working overtime for free.
